# Accessing to resources linked to a closed billing account at Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google

Hi all I have a GCP account that Google closed my billing account due to unpaid invoices.

It has been almost a year now that account remains closed. I need to know If I will have access to my resources in the project like my kubernetes clusters/workloads, DNZ zone, virtual machines etc after clearing out the payment issues and reopen the billing account?

It is almost not possible to access live chat so I hope I get an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Projects within GCP undergo a 30 day grace period before the resources are fully deleted. As the Project needs an active Billing account, which is automatically closed if there are unpaid invoices.

If the Project is already past [30 day grace period](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects:%7E:text=After%2030%20days%2C%20the%20project%20is%20fully%20deleted.:%7E:text=After%2030%20days%2C%20the%20project%20is%20fully%20deleted), the resources on that project are now fully deleted and cannot be recovered even if the Billing account is reestablished.

Comment: In general, this is true but not always. I have seen accounts not loose resources long after the 30 day grace period expired.

Comment: @Siegfred, are you sure about that? At the link in your reply says that it is for projects that shut down. In my situation project is still visible.

Comment: @Murat, Even though you didn't opt to shutdown your Project, it still needs an active Billing Account. If your resources are left unpaid, resources are sent back to the resource pool for reallocation to be deployed on Projects with active Billing Accounts.

Comment: @SiegfredV. so you mean that if the invoices gets paid tomorrow and billing account gets opened again, the resources will be allocated back to project so they will be available again?

Comment: @Murat, no, resources are only recoverable within the 30-day grace period after the Billing Account is closed, but as you said "It has been almost a year now". [At the end of the 30-day period, the project and all of its resources are deleted and cannot be recovered](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects). The project might still be visible, although its resources are deleted